# Cant call a view in codeignitor's admin, gives not found error

Tags: codeigniter

Im new to codeignitor and just given this project to add a few modules.So what I did was, I copied the code of an existing controller and pasted it in new one, changed the name of the class, called the view.
Now when I click the link, it goes on the controller file but unable to call the view? any help please!

Comment: Are you using codeigniter 3, if so first thing to check with codeigniter 3 is make sure all controllers, models etc have there first letter as uppercase on file and class name you may also need to have index.php in url

Comment: It could literally be caused by anything... how do you expect any meaningful assistance without showing us any code whatsoever?  Please review:  ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *"Cant call a view in codeignitor's admin"* ~ CodeIgniter is just a PHP framework; it doesn't have an admin page or a user authorization system unless you created them yourself.

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt to carefully read the documentation:  http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the newest version of CI, and given the small amount of info you supplied I recommend you check out this official resource: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: Uppercase letter issue!

Comment: Why would naming convention matters so much to CI?

Comment: thanks so much for the help :)